# Это не займёт больше минуты?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация, формулировка

В баннере незарегистрированному пользователю предлагается зарегистрироваться:

> [image: регистрация]

Только мне фраза "Это не займёт больше минуты" кажется странной? Чаще встречаю фразу "Это займёт не более минуты" в подобных случаях. Кто что думает?

Comment: Мне кажется, что суть не изменится, но на всякий случай задал [вопрос лингвистам](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/448809).

Comment: "Это быстро и не больно" :)

Comment: @Harry доктор, после регистрации меня начали преследовать фантомные боли.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На основании [рекомендаций](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/448809/183872) участников сообщества «Русский язык» [утвердил](https://ru.traducir.win/string/7336) перевод проблемной части в следующем виде:

> Это займёт не больше минуты:

Будет на сайте после подкачки и пересборки.

Comment: А можно с неразрывным пробелом, а то фигня: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLgF9.png

Comment: @Qwertiy у вас же есть доступ к правке и утверждению, как у модератора. Но по мне так, тут нет смысла по этому поводу заморачиваться.